# Unable to login to Chromium on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, chromium

Recently downgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 12.04 PP. While I can log in to my Google acct on Chromium, I cannot login to Chromium itself: receive "service unavailable; try again later" error. Thank you!

Comment: Are you aware the support for 12.04 will end soon?

Comment: Yes. The computer's main duty right now is helping me look for a job. Once employed again, I'd like to purchase a new computer and run a much newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: You can install/upgrade to any newer LTS release for free in the same computer and you already did it apparently but then *downgraded from Ubuntu 16 to 12.04* when there's **less than a month of support left**. I though you were unware of the fact, hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

The old LTS releases may still be "supported" but it appears they don't get all the latest versions of programs.

So it may have to do with the old version of Chromium in 12.04's default repos, maybe version 37 is no longer supported by Google, so it won't let you log into google services anymore.

See this [search of Ubuntu's packages for chromium](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=chromium-browser&searchon=names) to see that chromium-browser is only at:

- version 37.0.2062.120-0ubuntu0.12.04.4 in 12.04LTS, and
- version 55.0.2883.87-0ubuntu0.16.04.1263 in 16.04LTS (and essentially version 55.x in newer Ubuntu releases)
- version 53.0.2785.143-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1145 in 14.04LTS, I'm not sure why it's slightly older, but maybe it's at the point in time where the chromium-browser guys "give up" on old Ubuntu's?

You could try installing another newer version of Chromium, maybe even compiling from source?

Comment: Chromium on Trusty seems to be stuck at v53 because so far the package maintainer hasn't managed to build any newer versions for Trusty in his staging PPA.